# passing props as object to another component

Tags: reactjs

I have two components Editor.js and Overview.js, where I want to pass props as object to Overview.js. I want to pass the returned object i.e. fis to Overview component. Can I return something like this inside return of an arrow function as follows: Not sure if is the right approach

```
return (<Overview fis={this.props.fis} />)
```

```
class Editor extends React.Component{
  constructor(props, context){
  super(props, context);
}

display = () =>{
  for (let i=0; i<Data.length; i++) {
    if (id == Data[i].ID) {
      const fis = Data[i];
    }   
  }
  return fis;   
}

render() {
  return (
    <Button variant="primary" onClick={() => this.display()}>VIEW</Button>)
  }
}
```

Comment: The Question is unclear, You want to pass an object back to the parent component from child component?

Comment: @AjayGhosh Yes, I wan to pass returned fis from Editor.js to Overview.js

Comment: if so, 
Define a function in overview.js. Pass the function as props from overview.js to editor.js. Call that function from editor.js file with the value you need to pass as argument.

Comment: That should work. What's the issue? Call the passed function from inside the display function.

Comment: In display() where is 'id' coming from? You'd be better off with display = (id) => Data.find(d => id === d.ID);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can pass an object as a prop to another component directly. The code you have written in the `display()` is wrong as this is in the loop and out of scope outside the loop.

> In the below code, initially, the set `fisNewData` as `null` and
>   `onClick` the value will be set with filtered data.fisNewData will be
>   passed as props to Overview component.

```
  class Editor extends React.Component {
      state = { fisNewData: null };
      display = () => {
        const fis = Data && Data.filter(v => v.ID === id);
        this.setState({ fisNewData: fis });
      };

      render() {
        const { fisNewData } = this.state;
        return (
          <>
            <Button variant="primary" onClick={() => this.display()}>
              VIEW
            </Button>
            {fisNewData.length ? <Overview fis={fisNewData} /> : null}
          </>
        );
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Overview.js

```
class Overview extends React.Component{
    constructor(props, context){
    super(props, context);
    }
  const passingfunction = (passedvalue) =>
   {
     //Do something
   }
    render(){
        return (<Editor function={passingfunction}/>)
            }
}
```

Editor.js

```
class Editor extends React.Component{
    constructor(props, context){
    super(props, context);
    }
const display = () =>{
        for(let i=0; i<Data.length; i++)
        {
          if(id == Data[i].ID)
          {
          props.function(Data[i]);
          } 
        }
        }
    render(){
        return (
      <Button variant="primary"onClick={() => this.display()}>VIEW</Button>)
            }
}
```